# Temporary disable delivery of JMS message based on message property

Tags: java, jms, hornetq

I have a requirement which I am currently not aware of if it is possible at all. I would like to temporary disable the devliery of a JMS message if the message contains a specified property. Currently I am using HornetQ as message provider.

Let's make an example:

The queue contains of the following three entries:

```
{1, "foo", "A_CATEGORY"}
{2, "bar", "B_CATEGORY"}
{9, "bof", "A_CATEGORY"}
```

At a certain point the app must be able to tell the HornetQ message server that messages belonging to B_CATEGORY shouldn't be delivered at the moment (e.g. because the underlying database for B_CATEGORY objects gets updated). So the message with id 2 wouldn't be delivered at the moment, while 1 and 9 would be delivered as they have a different value for the category object.

It must happen out of the Java code without restarting the application at all. Is this possible at all?

Thanks for your help!

---

Just thought about an alternative design approach for this problem. Let's assume that the first Queue contains messages with all kind of categories (btw it isn't possible to create a queue per category as there could be a lot of them). This 'normal' queue is normaly configured (e.g. with no expiry, but DLQ).

Now if a listener consumes such a message and sees that it can't process messages belonging to a certain category, it puts it into a second queue. This queue is configured with redelivery delay and also an expiry time. If one sets now the expiry time quite high enough (of course not that the queue overflows) and the redelivery time not too short, then this should work out if there is no solution to the above question.

Of course one must calculate how many of those queue entries could be created during the time a category can't be processed. And also how long such an inavailability for a category could take so that the redelivery could be adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it is not possible with message driven beans.

A similar functionality is achievable with standard JMS consumer:

```
 MessageConsumer c = session.createConsumer(destination);
 while ( b-category-can-be-processed ) {
     Message m = c.receive();
     // process messages until b category is OK to be processed
 }

 c.close();

 // now create a different consumer with message selector ignoring "B_CATEGORY"
 MessageConsumer c1 = session.createConsumer(destination, "Category <> 'B_CATEGORY'");
 while ( b-is-locked ) {
     Message m = c1.receive();
     // process messages until b category is locked
 }

 c1.close();
 // go to start
```

This example assumes you're able to tell when to process B's again based on the messages received. If not, then you could resume the normal routine after certain time. The example also presents only a single thread of execution.

Exploring this path further, you could take a look at Spring's `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` — Spring message driven bean. It can do exactly what I described, but in a far more advanced way. It can be fed with a message selector, and it's live, you can change it any time you want. It handles messages in multiple threads, too, if you set the `concurrentConsumers` higher than 1.

As for your solution with redirecting messages to another queue while they cannot be processed, please notice that it generates extra traffic; you do want all your messages to be processed in the end, right? Why not leave them where they are and just fetch them in appropriate time? You won't have to estimate the redelivery delay ahead, which might be hard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Good point. Yeah agree that my second idea isn't nice. It was more intended as a What-To-Do-If-Not-Possible approach. Will take a look into your suggestion. Will come back.

Comment: just read through the javadoc of the DefaultMessageListenerContainer and it looks exactly what I was looking for (Spring is perfect).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a core queue (or a Subscription) with a filter and stop the queue using management API. Or if you are working embedded you could just cause pause at the Server Queue object.

As this would be a very custom feature, you could probably use it embedded, or make special adjustments at your own branch.